# modifying length of an array in C++

Tags: c++

If I have this float array declaration:

```
float tables[10];
```

How can I change the length of the 'tables' array to 20?

Another question related to the array in C++:

I can not declare an array something like this:

```
int length=10;

float newTables[length]; // error C2133: 'newTables' : unknown size
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine defining the size of array during build-time, you can use #define

```
#DEFINE ARRAY_SIZE 20
float tables[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Or if you need to specify the size of array during runtime, use new

```
float* newtables;
newtables = new float[20];
```

Comment: Worth noting that you must also delete the allocated memory when finished with it if you use 'new'

Comment: @Habba: for the line: newTables = new float[20], I got an error: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'float *' to 'float []'

Comment: @TomP89 I can delete the allocated memory. It should not be a problem.

Comment: @devn: I fixed the code. It seem that I'm not able to write code without an IDE. :)

Comment: yes, you are right! Declaring the pointer is simply fixed the code. THanks!

Comment: @devn: Be advised that this opens the door for a host of other problems - you should not be doing manual memory management in C++. Using `std::vector` is almost always the correct thing to do here.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot change the length of an array. In C++, you should use an `std::vector` for dynamic arrays:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector::size_type length = 10;
    std::vector<float> tables(length); // create vector with 10 elements
    tables.resize(20); // resize to 20 elemets
    tables[15] = 12; // set element at index 15 to value 12
    float x = tables[5]; // retrieve value at index 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C++ have a fixed length. If you want to stick with a pure array you need to allocate the memory dynamically using [malloc, realloc and free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc). However, you should prefer a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) for dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the length of an array dinamically while running program in C++. About the way you want to declare the array I suggest you the following:

```
const int length=10;
float newTables[length];
```

I'm not sure if it's what you want. In this case the variable "length" is a constant and can not be changed in execution.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I want to resize the length of an array after declaring it.